# .htaccess file causes internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

My site url is `http://localhost/Apps/index.php`; it works fine without an `.htaccess` file, but when i add an `.htaccess`, I receive the following error:

> `Internal Server Error`
>
> `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`
>
> `Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.`
>
> `More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

My `.htaccess` file code is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L, QSA]
```

PHP Error log:

> `[18-Oct-2014 10:32:34 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`

Apache error.log:

> `[Sat Oct 18 06:51:11.609106 2014] [core:alert] [pid 3068:tid 960] [client ::1:3539] C:/wamp/www/Apps/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

I am using a WAMP server. My file directory is: C:\wamp\www\Apps\index.php  the Apps folder also contains a .htaccess file.

Comment: Check your server error logs to see what's going on.

Comment: I am not sure about my code. this is my first code. when i remove my .htaccess file, my site run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `mod_reqrite` activated?
If not do so in your httpd.conf , by adding or modifying this:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
Else check your logs and add them to your post.

Comment: Here is error log:
 php_error.log:

 [18-Oct-2014 10:32:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

apache_error.log is: 

[Sat Oct 18 06:51:11.609106 2014] [core:alert] [pid 3068:tid 960] [client ::1:3539] C:/wamp/www/Apps/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

time not matter, they are the current error.
thanks.

Comment: [Sat Oct 18 06:51:11.609106 2014] [core:alert] [pid 3068:tid 960] [client ::1:3539] C:/wamp/www/Apps/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration